# Random number extractor getting weird values

Tags: javascript, html, math, random

I'm trying to get a random integer which is between two given values and has not been extracted yet with javascript.
To do that, I'm using the following code:

```js
var extracted = [];
function rand(){
var from = document.getElementById('from').value;
var to = document.getElementById('to').value;
var number = Math.floor(from) + Math.floor(Math.random() * to);
var alreadyextracted = (extracted.indexOf(number) > -1);
if(alreadyextracted){
 var maximum = Math.floor(to) - Math.floor(from);
 var count = extracted.length;
    if(count > maximum){document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='All numbers have been extracted.';}
 else{rand();}
}
else{document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=number;
extracted.push(number);
if(extracted[0] == number){var content = number;}
else{var before = document.getElementById('got').innerHTML;
var content = number + ', ' + before;}
document.getElementById('got').innerHTML=  content;
}
}
```

```html
From: <input id="from" value="1">
To: <input id="to" value="10">
<input type="button" value="Extract" onclick="rand()">
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="desc">Already extracted numbers:</div>
<div id="got"></div>
```

It works fine if i put a "from" value which is lower than 10, but, if it is greater, it gets a completely random integer and randomly says that all numbers have been extracted even if it's not true.
I don't see anything in the firefox console.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Getting random numbers and ignoring dups is almost never what any project really needs. What you want is not random numbers at all, but a specific set of numbers, in random order. So build the set first: create an array with the whole range, and then extract from it one at a time, randomly indexing the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong.

Fill an array with all of your range of numbers from smallest to largest.

Use a [Fisher/Yates/Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to mix the array.

Draw out as many numbers as you need.

(No code included on purpose because I didn't fix your problem)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was so stupid not to think about that! I'll follow your advise :)

Answer (score 2):

Spender is not wrong but the problem lies in the way you generate you random numbers:

```
var number = Math.floor(from) + Math.floor(Math.random() * to);
```

That's not the proper way to generate a number between min and max. This should be:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Use the method proposed by spender and then pick an element in the remaining set using this function (In this case min will be 0 and max the number of remaining elements-1)